# COM interface inheritance and interoperability

Tags: c#, c++, inheritance, com

I have a single COM object (native C++).

It exposes three interfaces:

```
DECLARE_INTERFACE_(IMain, IUnknown)
{
    ...
};

DECLARE_INTERFACE_(IBase, IUnknown)
{
    STDMETHOD_(void, Method1)(THIS)PURE;
};

DECLARE_INTERFACE_(IDerived, IBase)
{
    STDMETHOD_(void, Method2)(THIS)PURE;
};
```

Internally the above interfaces are implemented by two classes:

```
class CImpl1 : public CUnknown, public IBase
{
    public:
        ...
        DECLARE_IUNKNOWN
        STDMETHODIMP NonDelegatingQueryInterface(REFIID iid, void** ppv);
        STDMETHODIMP_(void) Method1();
    ...
};

class CImpl2 : public CUnknown, public IDerived
{
    public:
        ...
        DECLARE_IUNKNOWN
        STDMETHODIMP NonDelegatingQueryInterface(REFIID iid, void** ppv);
        STDMETHODIMP_(void) Method1();
        STDMETHODIMP_(void) Method2();
    ...
};
```

The main object has two sub-objects:

```
class CMain : public CUnknown
{
    public:
        ...
        DECLARE_IUNKNOWN
        STDMETHODIMP NonDelegatingQueryInterface(REFIID iid, void** ppv);
    ...
    private:
        ...
        CImpl1* m_impl1;
        CImpl2* m_impl2;
    ...
};
```

The main object exposes the interfaces as follows:

```
STDMETHODIMP CMain::NonDelegatingQueryInterface(REFIID iid, void ** ppv)
{
    if (iid == IID_IMain)
    {
        return GetInterface((IMain*)this, ppv);
    }
    if (iid == IID_IBase)
    {
        return m_impl1->NonDelegatingQueryInterface(iid, ppv);
    }
    if (iid == IID_IDerived)
    {
        return m_impl2->NonDelegatingQueryInterface(iid, ppv);
    }
    return CUnknown::NonDelegatingQueryInterface(iid, ppv);
}

STDMETHODIMP CImpl1::NonDelegatingQueryInterface(REFIID iid, void ** ppv)
{
    if (iid == IID_IBase)
    {
        return GetInterface((IBase*)this, ppv);
    }
    return CUnknown::NonDelegatingQueryInterface(iid, ppv);
}

STDMETHODIMP CImpl2::NonDelegatingQueryInterface(REFIID iid, void ** ppv)
{
    if (iid == IID_IBase)
    {
        return GetInterface((IBase*)this, ppv);
    }
    if (iid == IID_IDerived)
    {
        return GetInterface((IDerived*)this, ppv);
    }
    return CUnknown::NonDelegatingQueryInterface(iid, ppv);
}
```

Now, I want to consume this object in C#:

```
[Guid("..."),
  InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
internal interface IBase
{
    [PreserveSig]
    void Method1();
}

[Guid("..."),
  InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
internal interface IDerived : IBase
{
    [PreserveSig]
    new void Method1();
    [PreserveSig]
    void Method2();
}

[Guid("...")]
internal class MainClass
{
}

static void Main()
{
    // Load an instance of the main object using LoadLibrary(), GetProcAddress() for DllGetClassObject() and IClassFactory.CreateInstance().
    object o = ComHelper.LoadComObjectFromFile("...[DLL file path]...", typeof(MainClass).GUID, typeof(IMain).GUID);
    IBase base = o as IBase;
    IDerived derived = o as IDerived;
    IBase base2 = derived as IBase;

    base.Method1();    // statement 1
    derived.Method1(); // statement 2
    base2.Method1();   // statement 3
}
```

Statements 1 and 2 work as expected, executing m_impl1->Method1() and m_impl2->Method1() as expected.

The problem is statement 3. I want it to execute m_impl2->Method1(). Instead it is executing m_impl1->Method1(), and I don't understand why.

The point is that I want to be able to write generic methods in C# that can operate on either m_impl1/CImpl1 or m_impl2/CImpl2 using the IBase interface:

```
public void DoSomething(IBase base)
{
    ...
    base.Method1();
    ...
    IDerived derived = base as IDerived;
    if (derived != null)
    {
        derived.Method2();
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    ...
    DoSomething(base);
    DoSomething(derived);  // acts on m_impl1 rather than impl2!
    ...
}
```

However, that obviously can't work if casting the COM object to IBase always results in accessing m_impl1.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit: added methods to C# interface definitions in the 5th code block.

---

Edit 2: more clarifications.

The key point of focus is this code:

```
IDerived derived = o as IDerived;
IBase base2 = derived as IBase;
```

The cast in the first statement obviously operates on the main COM object instance. CMain::NonDelegatingQueryInterface() for IDerived should ensure that *derived* is effectively a reference to *m_impl2*.

Following on from the above, the cast in the second statement should operate on *m_impl2*. In other words, CDerived::NonDelegatingQueryInterface() should be executed instead of CMain::NonDelegatingQueryInterface(). In practice that isn't happening. It's CMain::NonDelegatingQueryInterface() that is executed, which suggests that *derived* is still a reference to the main COM object instance rather than *m_impl2*.

Comment: Can you show us how you have declared the methods in C# interface definition?

Comment: It is a quirk in C#, a COM interface can only derive from IUnknown or IDispatch.  You need to work around this restriction by including the members that you "inherited" from IBase.

Comment: @SimonMourier Sorry, didn't mean to leave them out. Done now.

Comment: @HansPassant Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but I think I have done that. Please refer to the newly filled interface definitions. If I'm misunderstanding, please could you explain more fully. Thanks!

Comment: You didn't, IDerived has *two* methods named Method1.  The first one inherited from IBase.  Simply declare two methods.  The name does not matter, consider naming the first one "Method1Base" or "Dummy".  They both map to the same C++ function, but that's an implementation detail of C++'s support for multiple inheritance.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you again... but still same result as before. I'm able to successfully call any method which is unique to IDerived (eg. "Method2"), which to me suggests I've got the interface declaration right. However, as soon as I cast the same object to IBase, the calls are being redirected to m_impl1 [instead of m_impl2]. Adding debug logging to all the NonDelegatingQueryInterface() functions shows that the *main* object (ie. not m_impl2) is being QI'd for IBase, and that seems to be why m_impl1 is being used.

Comment: @HansPassant I've added more clarification of the question.

Comment: Jeremy crickets.  Well, that is the way you wrote it.  Your CMain::QI recognizes requests for IBase and IDerived, even though it does not actually implement these interfaces.  It should fail them.  Or to put it another way, you wrote "nondelegating" but you are in fact delegating.  Incorrectly, rules for QI are very strict.  By now it is unclear what you meant to do, perhaps you want to google "aggregating iunknown".

Comment: Your code violates COM identity rules, which is the root cause of the problem. COM requires QI to be transitive: `a->QI(IID_X, &x); x->QI(IID_Y, &y)` is equivalent to `a->QI(IID_Y, &y)` assuming all `QueryInterface` calls succeed. (The result need not be identical, but it needs to be equivalent.) Your QI is not transitive. What you really have is the service pattern. Main offers two services "Big" (which implements Base and Derived) and "Small" (which implements only Base).

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for your response! To cut a potentially long reply short, I think that the code already uses aggregation. Context is DirectShow. CMain, CImpl1 and CImpl2 all inherit CUnknown. CMain::GetOwner() is passed as the pUnk parameter for the CUnknown base constructor when constructing m_impl1 and m_impl2. I think what I'm trying to do is aggregate two objects which expose the same interface. On the face of it that seems to be impossible.